# Modeling of a Wireless Channel with known BER

Tags: modeling, telecommunication, wireless-communication

I have to model through software a wireless (my choice: 3g,4g, 802.11...) channel with given Bit Error Rate. I'm searching some distributions, I'm reading tons of papers but I can't find how to simulate in realistic way the Channel.

The model should take as input a bit sequence and BER and produce the bit sequence as it could be received with noise.